# Java pgm calling into a DLL via JNI

Tags: dll, java-native-interface

I have a simple program that makes a call via JNI to a DLL wrote ini C#.
Now when I run my servlet on Tomcat within a 32 Bit JVM,  on a 64 bit PC, is the bitness of the DLL driven by the bitness of the JVM or of the Underlying hardware.
ie,  Do I need a 32 bit or 64 bit version of the DLL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match the JVM, 32-bit JVM = 32-bit DLL.